# Envío de Correos php

Tags: php

Buen día , tengo un problema  con el envío de correos  por php resulta que estoy enviando documentos adjuntos y cuando el correo de destino es Gmail  funcióna perfectamente pero si es Outlook o uno corporativo llegan los archivo pero no es posible abrirlos

Comment: Debes de dar más detalle respecto a la duda, te recomiendo leer la guía de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comprendo el problema no es de tu código. Fijate en los tipos de archivo que bloquea Outlook [Datos adjuntos bloqueados en Outlook](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/datos-adjuntos-bloqueados-en-outlook-434752e1-02d3-4e90-9124-8b81e49a8519)